# Joomla, display different templates for each article

Tags: templates, joomla

I have 2 Joomla templates installed on my site, I would like one of the pages to use the one template and the rest of the site to use the other template.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Joomla 1.5 it may be different in Joomla 1.0.

Yes it is possible, if the page is linked to a menu item.

Goto the Template manager (Extension/Template manager)

Select the template you want to use for all your pages and set it as default.

Open the template you want for the one pages. You will see a block "Menu assignment"
in there select the option "Select from list" and then select the Menu Item your page is linked to and save.